# Safari window.matchMedia handler not called

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, media-queries, matchmedia

I need to execute `doSomethingFunc`, when afterPrint happens. My code is working fine on all browsers, except the current Safari-Versions (Safari 10.1 on OSX and the Safari Browser from iOS 10.3). It seems that the event listeners (at least for print) are not called for these two browsers.

```
const mediaQueryPrint = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryPrint.addListener((mql) => {
    if (!mql.matches) {
        setImmediate(doSomethingFunc);
    }
});

window.print();
```

The code above works perfectly with OSX Safari 9.1.2 and Safari from iOS 10.2.
But not with the current versions.

Has somebody noticed something similar? Or do I have to improve my code for the current Safari versions?

My guess is, that this is a Safari bug, since there is a corresponding note in the Safari 10.1 [changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH12-DontLinkElementID_65) chapter Accessability.

Comment: Yes I've experience the same thing - Turns out (In my case) that it fires the handler just fine if the print is within 1 page. If the print is more than one page, it gets ignored completely. 

I haven't found any bug reports on it yet though.

Comment: yeah, I guess this feature is not used very often. I would be very glad, if you wrote a bug report on bugreport.apple.com. I did the same. Sadly apple is very intransparent with its bugs, so we do not know if apple noticed it already.

Answer (score -1):

Did you not want to call

```
        setImmediate(doSomethingFunc);
```

when

```
    mql.matches
```

is True? Why the '!' then?

Comment: if you say `!mql.matches` you are doing stuff during the afterPrint-Event and if you say `mql.matches` you are doing stuff during the beforePrint-Event.

Comment: just asking. your original question didn't state that you want the afterPrint-Event. Thanks for the down-vote and now I learn more about how SO works.